# SQL fecha cercana

Tags: base-de-datos, sql, tablas

Junto con saludarles y agradecer este espacio, les solicito ayuda con lo siguiente.
Tengo dos tablas.. la tabla1. es un registro de ventas historico con los campos fecha_vta, codigo_producto, cantidad. en la otra tabla tengo la variación de costos por producto por fecha con los siguientes campos fecha_costo, codigo_producto, costo. La idea es que según el histórico de ventas (tabla 1) busque el costo del producto (tabla 2) mas cercano o igual a la fecha de ventas.

#### tabla 1

```
fecha_vta                codigo_producto     cantidad 
--------                 ---------           ------------
5/5/2018                 prod1                      10
6/5/2018                 prod2                      5
6/5/2018                 prod1                      8
7/6/2018                 prod2                      20
15/6/2018                prod1                      3
```

#### Tabla 2

```
fecha_costo            codigo_producto          costo
----------------       ---------------------    -------
01/05/2018             prod1                      2
06/05/2018             prod1                      2,5
06/05/2018             prod2                      3
09/06/2018             prod1                      2,8
```

#### resultado esperado:

```
fecha_vta                codigo_producto     cantidad                  costo                       fecha_costo
------------               ---------------------- -----------                  -------                      ----------------
5/5/2018                 prod1                      10                           2                              01/05/2018
6/5/2018                 prod2                      5                             3                              06/05/2018
6/5/2018                 prod1                      8                             2,5                           06/05/2018
7/6/2018                 prod2                      20                           3                              06/05/2018
15/6/2018                prod1                      3                             2,8                           09/06/2018
```

La idea es que la consulta me traiga el costo del producto más cercano de la fecha_costo a la fecha_venta. ver en la tabla de resultado que el prod1 me trae tres costos distintos relacionados con la cercanía de la fecha de venta con la de la fecha de costo del producto.

La cercanía de la fecha actualmente esta buscando resultados iguales o menores, pero la fecha cercana debería buscar tanto si es igual, mayor o inferior y la mas cercana traerla y mostrarla. 
[image: en la fecha costo muestra 01/05/2018 pero debe ser 06/05/2018]

**

### en la fecha costo muestra 01/05/2018 pero debe ser 06/05/2018

**

Les agradezco vuestra ayuda o consejo para resolver este problema.

Comment: si tienes el sql deberias agregarlo, igual si buscas alguna fecha cercana, deberias de indicar algun rango maximo, minimo o medio para determinar cual es cercano a otra.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo fácil creando un campo que calcule la diferencia en días entre una fecha y otra, luego ordenando por ese campo y creando un ROW_NUMBER, por lo cual el primer registro de cada factura y producto tomaría el costo.

Adjunto como seria la consulta según la estructura y datos que das.

```
DECLARE @tabla1 TABLE (fecha_vta DATE, codigo_producto VARCHAR(10), cantidad INT)
DECLARE @tabla2 TABLE (fecha_costo DATE, codigo_producto VARCHAR(10), costo DECIMAL(20,2))

INSERT INTO @tabla1 VALUES('2018-05-05', 'prod1', 10)
INSERT INTO @tabla1 VALUES('2018-05-06', 'prod2', 5)
INSERT INTO @tabla1 VALUES('2018-05-06', 'prod1', 8)
INSERT INTO @tabla1 VALUES('2018-06-07', 'prod2', 20)
INSERT INTO @tabla1 VALUES('2018-06-15', 'prod1', 3)

INSERT INTO @tabla2 VALUES('2018-05-01', 'prod1', 2)
INSERT INTO @tabla2 VALUES('2018-05-06', 'prod1', 2.5)
INSERT INTO @tabla2 VALUES('2018-05-06', 'prod2', 3)
INSERT INTO @tabla2 VALUES('2018-06-09', 'prod1', 2.8)


;WITH CTE_Cercania AS
(
    SELECT T1.*, 
           T2.costo,
           T2.fecha_costo,
           ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,T1.fecha_vta,T2.fecha_costo)) Cercania,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T1.fecha_vta, T1.codigo_producto ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,T1.fecha_vta,T2.fecha_costo)) ASC) OrdenCercania 
      FROM @tabla1 T1
LEFT JOIN @tabla2 T2 ON T1.codigo_producto = T2.codigo_producto
--ORDER BY T1.codigo_producto, ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY,T1.fecha_vta,T2.fecha_costo)) ASC
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_Cercania WHERE OrdenCercania = 1
```